# Switching CSS to use asset pipeline in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a lot of legacy CSS files from what was a Rails 2.x app that got upgraded to Rails 3.2.8, and I want to switch over to using the Rails asset pipeline for stylesheets. The issue is, the CSS stuff is messy in terms of huge lines of code, duplicate file names, and unorganized folder structure.

After looking through individual pages, and trying to add individual stylesheets and folders into the asset pipeline and spending some cycles debugging, I realized there's probably a better approach.

Is there a way to test to make sure the old CSS matches up with the asset pipeline CSS? What are some good tools for testing and debugging CSS?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this episode of RailsCasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1 Also, make sure you upgrade from 3.2.8 to 3.2.14 as fast as you can for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is actually a pretty good question. i just know of one tool called [wraith](http://responsivenews.co.uk/post/56884056177/wraith) that takes screenshots of your page and compares diffs them. that allows for regression testing of your design. you will need to have a test for every page though.

if you look into your browser you also have the possibility to see which css selectors are not used. you could start by deleting the styles that are not used throughout your page.

i think that you will have to take the bitter pill and refactor your css bit by bit. sass and scss might help you with that.

at some point it might be better to start of with a clean slate though. just start with one page and create the css from scratch. at least you know how it has to look like...

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation with a large legacy application. While I haven't made the transtion yet, here are the steps I'm anticipating:

- Upgrade to latest Rails 3.2.x with asset pipeline disabled (done but still testing now)
- Upgrade to latest Rails 4.x (because asset pipeline changed between versions)
- Divide my css pages between those that apply to every page, and those that are page specific. For the asset pipeline, include ONLY those that apply to every page, and activate the pipeline.
- Over time, rewrite the CSS so that page specific rules can be included in the global rules, until everything is in the first category.

I'm seeing advantages in upgrading to rails 3.2 that have nothing to do with the asset pipeline, so that's a win. I have a number of CSS and JS files that do (or could) get loaded on every page without conflicts, so getting to that stage should be some improvement. Transitioning the remaining stylesheets can be done over time and hopefully in a safe way.

Hope this helps. I look forward to seeing any other answers from people that have made this sort of transition on a less-than-trivial web application.